# Image to bytes on IIS 8

Tags: c#, image, iis, byte, memorystream

On my web project I use the code below to get the bytes of an image.

```
    public byte[] imageToByteArray(Image image)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
            return ms.ToArray();    
        }
    }
```

When I debug my web application by Visual Studio, it starts the IIS Express (http://localhost:13153/) and the bytes obtained of the above method matches the image.

But, when I run my web application by IIS 8, directly on the browser "http://localhost/lab/testproject", the method return a completly wrong data.

Here is the results:

Debug by visual studio:

```
137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68,82,0,0,0,200,0,0,0,100,8,6,0,0,0,195,134,127,11,0,0,0,1,115,82,71,66,0,174,206,28,233,0,0,0,4,103,65,77,65,0,0,177,143,11,252,97,5,0,0,0,9,112,72,89,115,0,0,14,195,0,0,14,195,1,199,111,168,100,0,0,3,95,73,68,65,84,120,94,237,217,141,113,226,58,24,5,208,20,69,71,174,135,114,210,76,154,241,195,128,228,255,107,224,129,55,187,62,103,70,51,49,193,146,62,164,139,237,228,171,5,86,9,8,4,2,2,129,128,64,32,32,16,8,8,4,2,2,129,128,64,32,32,16,8,8,4,2,2,129,128,64,32,32,16,8,8,4,2,2,129,128,64,32,32,16,8,8,4,2,2,193,195,1,249,57,159,218,175,175,175,216,78,231,159,251,187,63,233,167,61,159,186,241,78,237,46,195,237,238,95,175,239,239,242,92,64,154,239,219,193,119,83,67,209,191,244,198,128,252,156,219,243,189,223,185,63,176,129,226,124,94,240,219,234,99,213,19,1,105,250,5,91,8,72,183,232,205,91,86,244,182,65,106,191,127,220,187,231,243,219,234,35,121,237,25,100,41,32,111,210,93,137,62,209,239,171,222,61,159,223,86,31,217,199,2,50,126,102,105,218,225,219,102,207,51,247,78,202,230,233,219,248,188,206,240,220,50,246,90,127,139,6,115,191,181,249,24,69,154,207,94,245,141,143,191,219,230,254,243,245,118,246,114,213,62,13,143,139,173,26,103,191,191,183,211,249,114,125,187,73,245,29,201,71,2,82,62,220,242,187,235,198,40,31,126,89,212,225,113,93,152,114,255,189,220,239,77,191,73,174,239,137,253,77,149,115,111,11,94,55,236,234,96,203,243,217,181,190,193,57,215,121,151,254,187,214,245,91,214,162,142,177,81,99,61,255,190,233,203,249,131,9,197,250,14,230,3,1,25,47,80,103,252,129,247,27,96,254,161,191,178,129,82,127,89,253,150,92,29,108,105,62,123,215,55,57,167,110,240,251,67,124,93,139,126,62,67,211,26,235,113,153,219,236,252,173,250,142,229,253,1,25,126,195,77,90,127,27,48,216,68,151,214,247,241,202,6,234,172,245,183,166,31,231,218,86,79,88,152,207,238,245,189,26,144,149,26,215,174,32,37,48,15,213,119,28,31,188,130,60,240,103,202,218,79,121,239,43,27,104,96,214,223,220,237,150,227,246,251,255,119,5,217,171,190,231,3,178,89,227,52,4,163,201,60,81,223,1,124,228,25,164,222,247,14,110,49,186,133,170,11,92,95,47,139,191,180,129,46,63,47,254,179,96,178,129,98,127,19,117,99,116,155,169,31,235,177,128,244,243,217,181,190,209,57,221,97,169,225,222,231,52,32,155,53,118,175,229,205,31,235,59,152,167,3,82,63,188,97,91,248,228,166,239,171,151,231,203,2,54,77,51,250,6,91,254,11,204,242,34,214,111,196,174,117,11,184,213,223,72,191,249,174,253,159,115,208,175,86,230,179,87,125,223,195,227,203,166,111,134,227,94,198,233,235,41,227,108,212,88,3,52,109,15,214,119,48,175,93,65,248,171,45,126,201,117,237,136,151,136,13,2,114,52,221,21,108,112,235,84,92,175,92,2,50,35,32,135,51,120,46,25,180,163,222,66,109,17,16,8,4,4,2,1,129,64,64,32,16,16,8,4,4,2,1,129,64,64,32,16,16,8,4,4,2,1,129,64,64,32,16,16,8,4,4,2,1,129,64,64,32,16,16,8,4,4,2,1,129,64,64,32,16,16,8,4,4,2,1,129,64,64,32,16,16,8,4,4,2,1,129,64,64,32,16,16,8,4,4,2,1,129,64,64,32,16,16,8,4,4,2,1,129,64,64,32,16,16,8,4,4,2,1,129,64,64,32,16,16,8,4,4,2,1,129,64,64,32,16,16,8,4,4,2,1,129,64,64,32,16,16,8,4,4,2,1,129,64,64,32,16,16,8,4,4,2,1,129,64,64,32,16,16,8,4,4,2,1,129,64,64,32,16,16,8,4,4,2,1,129,64,64,32,16,16,8,4,4,2,1,129,85,109,251,31,59,100,36,232,53,105,207,30,0,0,0,0,73,69,78,68,174,66,96,130
```

Run directly on IIS v8.5.9600.16384:

```
137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68,82,0,0,0,200,0,0,0,100,8,6,0,0,0,195,134,127,11,0,0,0,1,115,82,71,66,0,174,206,28,233,0,0,0,4,103,65,77,65,0,0,177,143,11,252,97,5,0,0,0,9,112,72,89,115,0,0,14,195,0,0,14,195,1,199,111,168,100,0,0,0,101,73,68,65,84,120,94,237,193,49,1,0,0,0,194,160,245,79,109,12,31,32,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,184,168,1,56,243,0,1,238,54,186,14,0,0,0,0,73,69,78,68,174,66,96,130
```

I tried different types of ImageFormat but with no success.

Anyone can say what is going on?

Very simple test:

```
var img = new Bitmap("<image-path>");
Response.Write(string.join(",", imageToByteArray(result)));
```

EDIT:

After some tests I found what is causing this problem.

```
private Bitmap _bitmap;
private void StartBrowser(string source)
{
    var th = new Thread(() =>
    {
        var webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
        webBrowser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
        webBrowser.DocumentCompleted +=
            webBrowser_DocumentCompleted;
        webBrowser.DocumentText = source;
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run();
    });
    th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    th.Start();
}

public void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var webBrowser = (WebBrowser)sender;
    _bitmap = new Bitmap(webBrowser.Width, webBrowser.Height))
    webBrowser.DrawToBitmap(_bitmap, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, _bitmap.Width, _bitmap.Height));
}
```

Only the Bitmaps created by this method has the mentioned problem.

Comment: Is the IIS v8.x a correct image or is it corrupted? if its corrupted try dumping the bytes to disk before you send them if see if they to are corrupted if arent then you atleast know its not the code that converts the image to bytes...

Comment: Both seem valid PNG sequences, but do they open on an image editor? Can you see anything in the second stream (i.e., the one from IIS 8.5?)

Comment: It really just looks like the 8.5 version has better compression... why do you think the image is broken?

Comment: The image is completly transparent when I use ImageFormat.Png and completly black when I use ImageFormat.Gif.

Comment: The simple test you have as example: where does the result come from and what happens to var img?

Comment: Maybe 32-64 mismatch ? Verify both versions of IIS are using the same 32 or 64

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run()` in a web app?